# PHP PDF functions

Tags: php, pdf

How do I generate PDF files with [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). **php.net** says that **pdflib** needs to be installed to use functions such as `new_pdf ()`.

However, **pdflib** is not free and the lite version is not allowed for commercial use. I am confused. I would have thought PHP would have some built-in functionality to create PDF files.

How do I get through this as I do not want to use libraries such as **fpdf**, etc.?

Comment: Why do you not want to use third-party libraries?

Comment: TCPDF is really good and easy to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP does not have any in-built functions, so you have to use libraries. **[TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)** is the easiest modules and it's free.

Comment: Thakyou Ritesh was just after confirmation iss try tcppdf

Comment: @BarryConnolly: :) . I had used **TCPDF**  lot of times in several website that i had constructed.Its very easy to use. The best part is you can **modify** it as per your wish. You can **customize** it too. Also, stack-overflow.com have many  answers/questions on TCPDF.

Answer (score 5):

You should try the following. They are some useful [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) libraries for [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) documents:

- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
- [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/)
- [DOM PDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)

See Stack Overflow questions *[Generate PDF from HTML PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444879/1435800)* and *[How to generate PDF files with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323269/how-to-generate-pdfs-with-php?rq=1)*.

It's your choice with which you feel more comfortable.

Comment: So there are no pdf functions shipped with php, a library it is then ..  thanks all

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use pdflib, you will have to use another third-party library.

Zend provides one as part of the [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework). But the ones we have used for various purposes are:

- [DomPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) is great for taking [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) and producing PDF files
- [tcPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) is a more class-based drawing style approach, but it works great and gives loads of control.